# Apply custom taxonomy archive template to children

Tags: taxonomy, archives

There is a slight problem that I cannot figure out by myself:

I created a custom post type (`tours`) with custom taxonomy (`tour categories`). I have created a `taxonomy-tour-categories.php` to display an `archive` page for each tour category. Works perfect.

I have a `tour category` (`School tours`) which needs a different layout, so I added a second template `taxonomy-tour-categories-shool-tours.php` with my desired layout. Again it works perfect.

The problem is that the `'school tours'` tour category has its own subcategories (like `'workshops'`, `'science labs'` and so on) which I would like to be displayed by the `taxonomy.tour-categories-school-tours.php` template, but are displayed by the `taxonomy.tours-categories.php` template. Why that?

I thought that wordpress - when a template file for a specific term is missing - would fall back to the immediately above level template file (in this case `taxonomy.tours-categories-school-tours.php`). What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please always read your question again before posting. Else you can use the "edit" link on the bottom of the question to fix grammar, spelling and MarkUp. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in this image](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png), template hierarchy limits to `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php`.

I don't know why a subterm falls back to `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`, but I guess it searches for a `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php` in wich `$term` would be `workshops`, `science labs` and so on. And since those don't exist (I suppose), it falls back on `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`.

You could make use of a workaround in your `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` file wich loads the requested `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php` file when the `$term` has a parent `$term`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the system looks for file names only. It doesn't do queries and calculations to work out hierarchies. There would be a lot of overhead to that.